# JS oop not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, wampserver

I'm developping a web site using WAMP, this is a part of code in my website. I even checked this block of code mentioned below.

html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Functions/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Functions/listControl.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var users= new regUsers('load','bef','full');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

javascript page

```
function regUsers(id,pos,detail)
    {
        /*
            usr001 all users
            usr002 search users on keyword
        */
        var self=this
        this.count=0;
        this.id='#' + id;
        this.pos=pos;
        this.amount=0;
        this.detail=detail;
        this.countReset= function(){this.count = 0;};
        this.getList=function()
            {
                console.log('count : ' + self.count);
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'Functions/list.php',
                    data:{req:'usr001',off:this.count,detail:this.detail,amount:self.amount},
                    success:function(ans){
                        if(ans=="")
                            return;
                        else
                        {

                            self.count += parseInt(self.amount);
                            switch(self.pos)
                            {                           
                                case 'bef':
                                    $(ans).insertBefore(self.id);
                                    break;
                                case 'app':
                                    $(self.id).append(ans);
                                    console.log(ans);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        this.findRec=function(keyW='',cls,field)
            {
                if(keyW=='')
                {
                    self.getList();
                    return;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'Functions/list.php',
                    data:{req:'usr002',keyW:keyW,detail:this.detail,field:field},
                    success:function(ans){
                        self.countReset();
                        $("."+ cls).remove();
                        switch(self.pos)
                        {                           
                            case 'bef':
                                $(ans).insertBefore(self.id);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    }
```

This code is properly work in Firefox, but not in internet explorer. In Internet explorer console, it is said that regUsers is not difined.

Comment: Can you please provide working example (e.g. jsfiddle) complete with your HTML and CSS? There could be something outside of this code provided that is causing the issue. Also - what version of Internet Explorer?

Comment: which version of **IE** and which version of **jQuery** are you using, please specify versions

Comment: Why do you have `body` inside `head`? Or was that a typo?

Comment: i corrected it, but error is still apearing as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that Internet Explore loads the JS files after it loads the inline script, I know it may not make much sense to do that but it might be a particular IE issue. What you could do is put your `var users= new regUsers('load','bef','full');` in a third JS file or you can assign the value to `users` in `unload` of the `body` tag i.e.

```
<body onload="users = new regUsers('load', 'bet', 'full')">
    . . .
</body>
```

This will insure that the your initialization code is executed after the webpage has loaded. Since `users` is declared with `var` it becomes a global variable, declaring with `var users = …` would have made it visible only in the scope of `onload`.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Functions/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Functions/listControl.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  </script>
 </head>
  <body onLoad="var users= new regUsers('load','bef','full');">
  
  </body>
 
</html>
 I changed html page as this, but error continues

Comment: I know this may sound like I'm insulting your intelligence but have you checked whether your file containing the regUsers is loaded